# Android show externally connected device in layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a device connected to my system.Its is in `USB debugging mode`.
 It is coming up when i click on play.

So i am deploying the application on that device.The problem is that every time i make any layout changes, I have  to run it on the device. Can this **externally** connected device be listed with the other device listed in the layout preview page?

Can i get a this device listed on the `layout preview` page with other devices that are listed there. Is this even possible?

Comment: no it is not possible dude !!!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get the actual device listed on the layout preview. But, you can create a Device Definition exactly similar to your device which will be automatically get listed there, so you don't even have to run the app to see the UI.

Start Android Virtual Device Manager from Eclipse-> Window-> Android Virtual Device Manager

Then go to "Device Definition" Tab Click on "New Device". There you can Specify everything regarding device Screen Size, Resolution, etc. Give a name to your device and your done.

Now, you can see your custom device preview in XML-> Graphical layout itself.

Comment: Welcome!!! Please, accept it as an answer,by clicking on Arrow on the left hand side, if its worked for you :)